# How would you represent text on the same place but with different images on each side?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, images, booklet

I've been working on a booklet for a client but I have no idea how shoud I do it

I have to put the text on the exact same place for every page, I can't get pass this one!

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your question is. Could you try to rephrase it in regards to the image you show?

Comment: Sorry I've been working on it for 10 hours and am a bit dizzy, How would you represent the images? IMG2 doesn't fit in like IMG1

Comment: That doesn't help. What do you mean "represent"? Why does img2 have to be that tall? What's the usage of this?

Comment: The IMG's represent a product, the product IMG2 is tall

Comment: Reduce img2 so it's height is more inline with other images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have many options if you really want to keep the text in the same exact position on all the pages. You can only shrink the size of all your images to have the same height.

[image: pictures smaller on a catalog layout]

You can have a look at catalogs to see how they do it. **It's acceptable to have a layout for vertically tall products and one for products that are more horizontally long.**

[image: 2 different layouts]

**Examples:**

Using 2 different layouts for 2 different type of products

[image: Layout for vertical and horizontal pictures]

Cropping the vertically tall image to the middle. Usually clients hate this though, they prefer to see the whole product. But maybe it can be suggested to your clients.

[image: cropping vertically high products on a catalog layout]

Comment: the problem with the vertical examples here is that it seems to emphasize the importance of the item, but the idea expressed is sound: if you are in a battle between unthinking consistency and appearance, err on the side of looking good.

Comment: It doesn't if the proportions are right. Personally I think it's better to keep the same proportion no matter the image, this way the vertically high image won't look like it's smaller than the other one in real. The other benefit of having 2 different layouts is there's less empty white space. But as you say, it's a battle between consistency and appearance! Not easy to fit these images beautifully in a design with only one layout style. That layout needs to be created to welcome both kind of images!

Comment: So its clear, I think you have a good answer. I do a lot with imagery of artwork, which are usually "very landscape" or "very portrait." Usually I have to make the vertical images a little bit smaller. Like a horizontal might be 8 wide, but a vertical image might need to be 7.25 high on the same spread. Of course portrait aspect paintings tend to have a larger subject central to the composition...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ended up doing your second way. Text was a really big problem too, the client wanted to keep it simple with 4-5 lines of text per page. But thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it helps! Very hard to do these layouts with different orientation for the images and not much texts. But it can also look very stylish to have 2 different styles and lot of white space. Good luck!